# Date picker behave different in iphone 5 and iphone4?

Tags: iphone, datepicker, uitextfield, ios6.1

I have a problem with date picker ,Actually in iphone 4 it worked nicely and get the data but iphone 5 the data is not displayed in the textfield.I hope to get the valuable feedbacks

Comment: please add some code or screenshot of your error.

Comment: Please,add some code or screen shot for clarification

Answer (score 1):

I doubt what you are trying to accomplish. Are you not able to get proper data in your date picker or you are not being able to retrieve data from picker and display it in textfield.